# 'opencv2/opencv.hpp' file not found macOS

Tags: python, macos, opencv

**Problem/Question:**

I am getting `fatal error: 'opencv2/opencv.hpp' file not found` when I run the `make` command when trying to install gst-plugins-vr. What do I need to do to fix this issue?

**Background:**

I am trying to install gst-plugins-vr according to the following article: https://medium.com/@yofujimo/how-to-make-vr180-videos-from-stereoscopic-clips-b1fcab0bc020

I have macOS Catalina version 10.15.7 installed.

When I run the `make` command, I am getting the following errors (I've included the terminal output as images and text below).

[Error message part 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RkWOR.png)
[Error message part 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7CQ70.png)

> [9/31] Compiling C object
> libgst3d-1.0.0.dylib.p/gst-libs_gst_3d_gst3dmesh.c.o
> ../gst-libs/gst/3d/gst3dmesh.c:137:27: warning: passing 'gint *' (aka
> 'int *') to parameter of type 'const GLuint *' (aka 'const unsigned
> int *') converts between pointers to integer types with different sign
> [-Wpointer-sign]
> gl->DeleteBuffers (1, &buf->location);
> ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ../gst-libs/gst/3d/gst3dmesh.c:253:22: warning: passing 'gint *' (aka
> 'int *') to parameter of type 'GLuint *' (aka 'unsigned int *')
> converts between pointers to integer types with different sign
> [-Wpointer-sign]   gl->GenBuffers (1, &attrib_buffer->location);
> ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ 2 warnings generated. [14/31] Compiling C object
> libgst3d-1.0.0.dylib.p/gst-libs_gst_3d_gst3drenderer.c.o FAILED:
> libgst3d-1.0.0.dylib.p/gst-libs_gst_3d_gst3drenderer.c.o  cc
> -Ilibgst3d-1.0.0.dylib.p -I. -I.. -I/usr/local/Cellar/glib/2.66.7/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/local/Cellar/glib/2.66.7/lib/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/pcre/8.44/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/libffi/3.3_2/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/glib/2.66.7/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/gstreamer/1.18.3/include/gstreamer-1.0 -I/usr/local/Cellar/gst-plugins-base/1.18.3/include/gstreamer-1.0 -I/usr/local/Cellar/gst-plugins-base/1.18.3/lib/gstreamer-1.0/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/orc/0.4.32/include/orc-0.4 -I/usr/local/Cellar/graphene/1.10.2/include/graphene-1.0 -I/usr/local/Cellar/graphene/1.10.2/lib/graphene-1.0/include -I/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/../../include/openhmd -I/usr/local/Cellar/hidapi/0.10.1/include/hidapi -I/usr/local/Cellar/assimp/5.0.1/../include/include -Xclang -fcolor-diagnostics -pipe -Wall -Winvalid-pch -g -DHAVE_OPENHMD=1 -mfpmath=sse -msse -msse2 -Wno-pedantic -MD -MQ libgst3d-1.0.0.dylib.p/gst-libs_gst_3d_gst3drenderer.c.o -MF
> libgst3d-1.0.0.dylib.p/gst-libs_gst_3d_gst3drenderer.c.o.d -o
> libgst3d-1.0.0.dylib.p/gst-libs_gst_3d_gst3drenderer.c.o -c
> ../gst-libs/gst/3d/gst3drenderer.c
> ../gst-libs/gst/3d/gst3drenderer.c:49:27: error: use of undeclared
> identifier 'GL_DEBUG_SOURCE_APPLICATION'   gl->DebugMessageInsert
> (GL_DEBUG_SOURCE_APPLICATION,
> ^ ../gst-libs/gst/3d/gst3drenderer.c:50:7: error: use of undeclared identifier 'GL_DEBUG_TYPE_OTHER'
> GL_DEBUG_TYPE_OTHER,
> ^ ../gst-libs/gst/3d/gst3drenderer.c:51:10: error: use of undeclared identifier 'GL_DEBUG_SEVERITY_HIGH'
> 1, GL_DEBUG_SEVERITY_HIGH, strlen (message), message);
> ^ 3 errors generated. [23/31] Compiling C++ object libgstfreenect2.dylib.p/gst_freenect2_gstfreenect2src.cpp.o FAILED:
> libgstfreenect2.dylib.p/gst_freenect2_gstfreenect2src.cpp.o  c++
> -Ilibgstfreenect2.dylib.p -I. -I.. -I/usr/local/Cellar/glib/2.66.7/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/local/Cellar/glib/2.66.7/lib/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/pcre/8.44/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/libffi/3.3_2/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/glib/2.66.7/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/gstreamer/1.18.3/include/gstreamer-1.0 -I/usr/local/Cellar/gst-plugins-base/1.18.3/include/gstreamer-1.0 -I/usr/local/Cellar/gst-plugins-base/1.18.3/lib/gstreamer-1.0/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/orc/0.4.32/include/orc-0.4 -I/usr/local/Cellar/graphene/1.10.2/include/graphene-1.0 -I/usr/local/Cellar/graphene/1.10.2/lib/graphene-1.0/include -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/../../include/openhmd -I/usr/local/Cellar/hidapi/0.10.1/include/hidapi -Xclang -fcolor-diagnostics -pipe -Wall -Winvalid-pch -Wnon-virtual-dtor -g -mfpmath=sse -msse -msse2 -MD -MQ libgstfreenect2.dylib.p/gst_freenect2_gstfreenect2src.cpp.o -MF
> libgstfreenect2.dylib.p/gst_freenect2_gstfreenect2src.cpp.o.d -o
> libgstfreenect2.dylib.p/gst_freenect2_gstfreenect2src.cpp.o -c
> ../gst/freenect2/gstfreenect2src.cpp
> ../gst/freenect2/gstfreenect2src.cpp:39:10: fatal error:
> 'opencv2/opencv.hpp' file not found
> #include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
> ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ 1 error generated. [24/31] Compiling C++ object libgstfreenect2.dylib.p/gst_freenect2_gstfreenect2.cpp.o ninja:
> build stopped: cannot make progress due to previous errors. [1/9]
> Compiling C object
> libgst3d-1.0.0.dylib.p/gst-libs_gst_3d_gst3drenderer.c.o FAILED:
> libgst3d-1.0.0.dylib.p/gst-libs_gst_3d_gst3drenderer.c.o  cc
> -Ilibgst3d-1.0.0.dylib.p -I. -I.. -I/usr/local/Cellar/glib/2.66.7/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/local/Cellar/glib/2.66.7/lib/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/pcre/8.44/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/libffi/3.3_2/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/glib/2.66.7/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/gstreamer/1.18.3/include/gstreamer-1.0 -I/usr/local/Cellar/gst-plugins-base/1.18.3/include/gstreamer-1.0 -I/usr/local/Cellar/gst-plugins-base/1.18.3/lib/gstreamer-1.0/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/orc/0.4.32/include/orc-0.4 -I/usr/local/Cellar/graphene/1.10.2/include/graphene-1.0 -I/usr/local/Cellar/graphene/1.10.2/lib/graphene-1.0/include -I/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/../../include/openhmd -I/usr/local/Cellar/hidapi/0.10.1/include/hidapi -I/usr/local/Cellar/assimp/5.0.1/../include/include -Xclang -fcolor-diagnostics -pipe -Wall -Winvalid-pch -g -DHAVE_OPENHMD=1 -mfpmath=sse -msse -msse2 -Wno-pedantic -MD -MQ libgst3d-1.0.0.dylib.p/gst-libs_gst_3d_gst3drenderer.c.o -MF
> libgst3d-1.0.0.dylib.p/gst-libs_gst_3d_gst3drenderer.c.o.d -o
> libgst3d-1.0.0.dylib.p/gst-libs_gst_3d_gst3drenderer.c.o -c
> ../gst-libs/gst/3d/gst3drenderer.c
> ../gst-libs/gst/3d/gst3drenderer.c:49:27: error: use of undeclared
> identifier 'GL_DEBUG_SOURCE_APPLICATION'   gl->DebugMessageInsert
> (GL_DEBUG_SOURCE_APPLICATION,
> ^ ../gst-libs/gst/3d/gst3drenderer.c:50:7: error: use of undeclared identifier 'GL_DEBUG_TYPE_OTHER'
> GL_DEBUG_TYPE_OTHER,
> ^ ../gst-libs/gst/3d/gst3drenderer.c:51:10: error: use of undeclared identifier 'GL_DEBUG_SEVERITY_HIGH'
> 1, GL_DEBUG_SEVERITY_HIGH, strlen (message), message);
> ^ 3 errors generated. [2/9] Compiling C++ object libgstfreenect2.dylib.p/gst_freenect2_gstfreenect2src.cpp.o FAILED:
> libgstfreenect2.dylib.p/gst_freenect2_gstfreenect2src.cpp.o  c++
> -Ilibgstfreenect2.dylib.p -I. -I.. -I/usr/local/Cellar/glib/2.66.7/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/local/Cellar/glib/2.66.7/lib/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/pcre/8.44/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/libffi/3.3_2/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/glib/2.66.7/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/gstreamer/1.18.3/include/gstreamer-1.0 -I/usr/local/Cellar/gst-plugins-base/1.18.3/include/gstreamer-1.0 -I/usr/local/Cellar/gst-plugins-base/1.18.3/lib/gstreamer-1.0/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/orc/0.4.32/include/orc-0.4 -I/usr/local/Cellar/graphene/1.10.2/include/graphene-1.0 -I/usr/local/Cellar/graphene/1.10.2/lib/graphene-1.0/include -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/../../include/openhmd -I/usr/local/Cellar/hidapi/0.10.1/include/hidapi -Xclang -fcolor-diagnostics -pipe -Wall -Winvalid-pch -Wnon-virtual-dtor -g -mfpmath=sse -msse -msse2 -MD -MQ libgstfreenect2.dylib.p/gst_freenect2_gstfreenect2src.cpp.o -MF
> libgstfreenect2.dylib.p/gst_freenect2_gstfreenect2src.cpp.o.d -o
> libgstfreenect2.dylib.p/gst_freenect2_gstfreenect2src.cpp.o -c
> ../gst/freenect2/gstfreenect2src.cpp
> ../gst/freenect2/gstfreenect2src.cpp:39:10: fatal error:
> 'opencv2/opencv.hpp' file not found
> #include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
> ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ 1 error generated. ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed. make: *** [all] Error 1

Comment: You need to make sure that the include folder was added correctly.

Comment: Thank you! What approach should I use to include the folder correctly? I've tried to update the .bash-profile file with "export PATH=/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/4.5.1_3/include/opencv4/opencv2:$PATH" and typing echo $PATH into the terminal returns '/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/4.5.1_3/include/opencv4/opencv2:/usr/local/bin:/Users/<username>/.pyenv/shims:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Applications/VMware Fusion.app/Contents/Public"